# Plug Parser: raising ParseError

Tags: json, elixir, html-parsing, plug

I'm writing a Plug Parser that among other things decodes JSON using Poison (I'd prefer to let `Plug.Parsers.JSON` do that, but I need to read the raw request body to verify it against a signature, so that's not possible).

I'm using [`Poison.decode/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/poison/Poison.html#decode/2) to decode the json. This returns an `{:error, ...}` tuple on error. As a Plug parser, I think I am expected to raise [`Plug.Parsers.ParseError`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.ParseError.html) if there was an error during the parsing. However `ParseError` expects an `exception` struct. I don't have one of those, I only have the tuple returned from `Poison.decode/2`.

As a workaround, I can use use [`Poison.decode!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/poison/Poison.html#decode!/2) and `rescue` the raised error, re-raising it as a `ParseError`, but that seems weird when the non-raising `decode/2` is available.

So my questions are, in increasing abstractness:

1. How do I raise a `ParseError` from a parser without a source exception?
2. Do I need to raise the `ParseError`, or it it better to raise my own exception?
3. Is there a better way altogether, allowing me to verify the signature without re-implementing the JSON parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (I'd prefer to let `Plug.Parsers.JSON` do that, but I need to read the
>   raw request body to verify it against a signature, so that's not
>   possible).

...

> 3. Is there a better way altogether, allowing me to verify the signature without re-implementing the JSON parsing?

Letting `Plug.Parsers.JSON` do that is in fact the best option. Since version 1.5.1 it's possible to provide a [custom body reader](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html#module-custom-body-reader) to the parser that can cache the body for later use. This is a much more generic solution than re-implementing a JSON-parser plug.

Here is my custom reader:

```
def read_body(conn, opts) do
  case Plug.Conn.read_body(conn, opts) do
    {res, body, conn} when res in [:ok, :more] ->
      {res, body, update_in(conn.assigns[:raw_body], &((&1 || "") <> body))}

    unknown ->
      unknown
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I raise a `ParseError` from a parser without a source exception?

You are expected to create the [`Plug.Parsers.ParseError`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.ParseError.html) yourself:

```
raise %Plug.Parsers.ParseError{exception: %MyException{message: "Failed to parse"}}
```

> Do I need to raise the `ParseError`, or it it better to raise my own exception?

You might raise whatever you want, but since it’s indeed `ParseError` I do not see any reason to raise something different.

> Is there a better way altogether [...]

This one is too opinionated. JSON parsing seems to be OK.

Comment: Attempting to raise the error like that causes `** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Plug.Parsers.ParseError.exception/1` because ParserError expects to be passed an `exception` argument that is a struct.

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow screwed up a part of the code; There is no such thing as “exception instance” in Elixir due to obvious reasons; It actually accepts [any struct having `message` field](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.6.0/lib/plug/parsers.ex#L38).

Comment: Yeah that's the reason for my question. I have to create a struct that looks like an "exception" just to raise `ParseError`. In that case I might as well just raise my own Exception. Seems like `ParseError` wasn't written with this usage in mind.

Comment: It is a generic wrapper for the `Plug` internals to pattern match it and handle it in a common way. It surely was written with this particular usage in mind.

Comment: In the two cases I can find in the Plug repository itself when `ParseError` is raised, it's is wrapping a rescued exception, not constructing a `ParseError` from unraised error cases.

Comment: That is true; the custom code in e.g. my own projects on top of phoenix uses a single specific handler for all types of _parsing errors_. After all, this exception is dedicated to parsing errors and yours seems to be a parsing error, so I don’t see any reason to reinvent a wheel and raise something else.

Comment: Yeah. I decided to stick with `ParseError`, but to feed it the error generated from `Poison.decode!/2` after all. Seems the cleanest way.